# touchesBegan() Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7, touchesbegan

I am creating a simple spritekit game where you try to drop balls into a hole and you score points for doing so. I have 2 labels at the top of the screen which are the "Balls left: #" and "Score: #". I am using the **touchesBegan method** to signal that a ball should drop from the point where they touch the screen. When they touch the screen, I also want to decrease the number of balls they have left by one and then update the "Balls Left" label. However, when I try to implement the code that simultaneously drops a ball and decreases the ball count by one, the ball doesn't appear but the score label updates correctly. I think this is because the label update is overriding the function that drops the ball. Any recommendations on how to fix this would be fantastic! My code is down below! Thanks in advance :)

**This is the code I have in my GameScene.swift**

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball")

            ball.xScale = 0.04
            ball.yScale = 0.04
            ball.position = touch.locationInNode(self)


            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 2)

            self.addChild(ball)
        }


    }
```

**This is the code I have in my viewController.swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        ballsLeftInt -= 1
        testEndGame()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your total ball number to limit the generated ball count.
Assume you want the player to have 10 balls to drop in each game.
In your GameScene.swift, set global value

```
var ballNum = 10
```

Then update it in the TouchesBegin method

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if ballNum > 0 {

        for touch in touches {

            let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball")

            ball.xScale = 0.04
            ball.yScale = 0.04
            ball.position = touch.locationInNode(self)


            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 2)

            self.addChild(ball)
            ballNum -= 1
            //tell VC to update the two labels in your VC
        }

    }else {
        //tell VC game over and reload ballNum after user click replay
    }
}
```

The way to tell VC can be achieved by using observer with NSNotificationCenter.

So, in the VC's view did load, you have to add two observers, one for update UI labels, one for game over.

In the VC, rewrite the viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateScore), name: "updateScore", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.informGameOver), name: "informGameOver", object: nil)

}
```

And add two functions,

```
    func updateScore() {
    // update your labels
}

func informGameOver() {
    // tell the player game over and offer the play again button
}
```

Now, get back to the touchesBegan method you can tell VC by post notifications, the final method is like

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

if ballNum > 0 {

    for touch in touches {

        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball")

        ball.xScale = 0.04
        ball.yScale = 0.04
        ball.position = touch.locationInNode(self)


        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 2)

        self.addChild(ball)
        ballNum -= 1
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateScore", object: nil)
    }

}else {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("informGameOver", object: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help, I didn't even know that the NSNotificationCenter reference existed. Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem I was having though . The balls still don't appear when I tap on the screen. However the label update is still working.

Comment: @jj_hennessy Yes you can, for example by flag this answer as the correct answer to this question so people who look your question see immediatly you have solve, good luck.